# return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); Thread 1: SIGBART

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, simulator

Whenever I try and run my app, this is the error message that occurs

**viewController.h**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end
```

---

**viewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    [super viewDidLoad];

    label.text = @"Number";

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}


- (IBAction)numberButton {

    int number;
    number = arc4random() %100;

    // Turns the integer (number) into a string
    NSString *numberDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", number];

    // Because the text has to be a string, i.e. an NSString
    label.text = numberDisplay;

}

- (IBAction)numButton {

    int number;
    number = arc4random() %100;

    // Turns the integer (number) into a string
    NSString *numberDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", number];

    // Because the text has to be a string, i.e. an NSString
    label.text = numberDisplay;

}

- (IBAction)color {

    int color;
    color = rand() %4;

    switch (color) {
        case 0:
            label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;

        case 1:
            label.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
            break;

        case 2:
            label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            break;

        case 3:
            label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}

- (IBAction)fontSize {

    int fontSize;
    fontSize = rand() %6;

    switch (fontSize) {
        case 0:
            [label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size:5]];
            break;

        case 1:
            [label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size: 15]];
            break;

        case 2:
            [label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size: 25]];
            break;

        case 3:
            [label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size: 35]];
            break;

        case 4:
            [label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size: 40]];
            break;

        case 5:
            [label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size: 45]];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

My .h has all of the same actions. I have checked and rechecked if there were spelling mistakes and/or connection mistakes. What else could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please state more clearly in the question what's the issue?

Comment: Please make sure your code is properly highlighted, also i cannot find any error message in between the lines.

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint and let us know which line you are crashing at. Also, post the full symbolicated stack trace.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I apologize for the poor formatting of my code, this was my first time on the site

Comment: I fixed it. There was an issue within the view controller in the storyboard, that upon pressing the yellow button, I was able to delete. Thanks though for all helpful comments and answers! I will formulate my code better next time! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take out the

```
int number; 
number = arc4random() %100;
```

in the actions. It is not necessary to have them.

Comment: How does this address OP's problem with their crash? Also, OP is setting a text label with the result of `number` so removing this code will not actually help.

Comment: OK - but it's still not an answer. At best it should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I try your code in a test project and it works well.

I think perhaps you make a mistake in connection. Confirm your IBAction connection has no redundant ones.

Here is my code(Actually I change nothing nearly):

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController()

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel * label;

@end

@implementation ViewController


@synthesize label;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    [super viewDidLoad];

    label.text = @"Number";

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}


- (IBAction)numberButton {

    int number;
    number = arc4random() %100;

    // Turns the integer (number) into a string
    NSString *numberDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", number];

    // Because the text has to be a string, i.e. an NSString
    label.text = numberDisplay;

}

- (IBAction)numButton {

    int number;
    number = arc4random() %100;

    // Turns the integer (number) into a string
    NSString *numberDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", number];

    // Because the text has to be a string, i.e. an NSString
    label.text = numberDisplay;

}

- (IBAction)color {

    int color;
    color = rand() %4;

    switch (color) {
        case 0:
            label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;

        case 1:
            label.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
            break;

        case 2:
            label.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            break;

        case 3:
            label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}

- (IBAction)fontSize {

    int fontSize;
    fontSize = rand() %6;

    switch (fontSize) {
        case 0:
            [label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size:5]];
            break;

        case 1:
            [label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size: 15]];
            break;

        case 2:
            [label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size: 25]];
            break;

        case 3:
            [label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size: 35]];
            break;

        case 4:
            [label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size: 40]];
            break;

        case 5:
            [label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size: 45]];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

@end
```